# two-byte operating system does not what I want

Tags: assembly, bochs, x86-16

I created a floppy boot image from an [example](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev3.html), it should:

1. disable all interrups
2. reboot

However, once I start it with bochs, it consumes 100% CPU until I kill it.

Here is the floppy image:

```
$ hd floppy.img
00000000  fa f4 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000010  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
00168000
```

Disassembled image:

```
$ objdump -b binary -D floppy.img -m i386

floppy.img:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 :
       0:   fa                      cli    
       1:   f4                      hlt    
    ...
     1fe:   55                      push   %ebp
     1ff:   aa                      stos   %al,%es:(%edi)
```

[Bochs output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6052055/) (pastebin).

bochsrc.txt:

```
romimage:    file=/usr/share/bochs/BIOS-bochs-latest, address=0xe0000
vgaromimage: file=/usr/share/bochs/VGABIOS-lgpl-latest 
floppya: 1_44=floppy.img, status=inserted 
boot: a
log: OSDev.log
mouse: enabled=0
megs: 32
display_library: sdl
```

I run bochs this way:

However, once I start it with bochs, it consumes 100% CPU until I kill it.

```
$ bochs -f bochsrc.txt
```

Bochs version: 2.4.6-4, running on ubuntu 12.04 i686.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What will it do after rebooting? Reboot again?

Comment: `hlt` does not reboot. That's not what it's for. It pauses the processor until an interrupt arrives, and since you've disabled interrupts....

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young then why does the emulator consume 100% CPU?

Comment: @JanDvorak Presumably because it's how the emulator is implemented. I think if you do this on a real CPU, it should not busy-loop; I know that (some versions of) Linux use `hlt` to idle the processor.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I still think it's on-topic. Was it you who closevoted?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young indeed. Everything is all right, I just misread the tutorial: it is not supposed to reboot. If you made an answer instead of a comment, I could mark it "correct"

Comment: @JanDvorak No, I didn't vote to close the question.

Comment: @MotiejusJakštys Okay, I've posted an answer that summarises this thread. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hlt` does not reboot; that's not what it's for. It pauses the processor until an interrupt arrives, and since you've disabled interrupts, it will just sit there doing nothing forever.

As to why the emulator consumes 100% CPU, that's probably due to the way the emulator is implemented. On (some versions of) Linux, `hlt` is used to idle the processor until the next timeslice, so of course it doesn't make the processor busy-wait. :-)

Answer (score 1):

CLI will not disable NMI (not maskable interrupts) so, following code is still better:

```
.loop:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp .loop
```

It is not clear why Bochs gives 100% CPU load. How you are checking this load? By the real CPU load, or Bochs has it's own virtual CPU load indicator?

I would suggest trying with another virtual machine, like QEMU.

So, the above code will boot and then sleep. If the intention is to reboot the computer, following code should do cold restart

```
    jmp $ffff:$0000
```

For warm restart:

```
    mov  [$472], 1234h
    jmp  $ffff:$0000
```

Comment: Except that this code also doesn't do what the OP is trying to do.